# Server is getting a different request then what I assembled

Tags: javascript

So I have these three lines of javascript:

```
    var source = "text/" + image + ".html";
alert(source);
document.getElementById('imgtext').src = source;
```

The alert box is showing me text/Maintainance/img7.html which is correct and exactly what it should be (more importantly, that file actually exists).

imgtext is an iframe, so the text in the html document should be loading into the frame.  Instead, I get a 404 error which says the server tried to retrieve /text/Maintainance.html/img13.html (which obviously doesn't exist).  There is absolutely no code between the alert and setting the source for the iframe.  I am testing this with chrome and firefox, both give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use jquery to access `imgtext` instead of `doc.getElementById`. `$('#imgtext').src = source;` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use jquery for this project.

Comment: `<html>`
` <head></head>`
` <body>`
  `<iframe id="imgtext" width="100px" height="100px" src=""></iframe>`
`  <script type="text/javascript">`
   `document.getElementById("imgtext").src="www.google.com";`
  `</script>`
 `</body>`
`</html>`

Comment: that worked for me ^^ sorry the code text didn't come out right

Comment: Even document.getElementById('imgtext').src = 'text/Maintainance/img1.html'; gives me that same thing, with the extra .html in there. The iframe tags are literally just <iframe id="imgtext"></iframe>.  Something is really messed up.

Comment: in the `<iframe>` tag make sure you declare an empty src attribute, like so:

Comment: yeah I did that.  It is like the .src attribute is being changed before the request is made, but I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: is your script before or after the element is inserted into the document?

Comment: After.  The iframe is loading a text description of an image when the user clicks on the image's thumbnail.  if you are wondering how the files are laid out, the javascript is in a separate file and gets included in the head section.

Comment: alright i'll mockup a better example now that I know what you're doing

Comment: I see your problem. It's not working for me either just changing an image on document load. Still looking....

Comment: I found it.  I was using single quotes in the getElementById, like I have been all along... switching them to double quotes fixed it.  wtf... single quotes worked for literally every other place I accessed an element that way...